# Probability of the arrangements of 10 Boys and 6 Girls in a Row.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Ten male friends and six female friends line up next to the bus stop in a row. Everyone just positions themselves at random. What is the probability that no two females are sitting next to each other?

I have worked out that the size of the sample space is $16!$. I am not sure if there is a more effective method than to do cases.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Alternately, we can use as sample space the  $\binom{16}{6}$ words of length $16$ that have $6$ F and $10$ M.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

First line up all the males, that can be done in $10!$ ways. Now this creates $11$ spaces between the males (including the space before the first male and the space after the last male). Now the first female has $11$ options to choose from, once she chooses her place, the second one has $10$ options and so on.

Answer (score 1):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ If we can represent man by $\bf{M}$ and Women by $\bf{W}$, Then we use Gap Method.

So Arrangements as $$_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_$$

Above $10$ man can be arrange as $10!$ (Here Man and women all are Different)

Now We can Arrange $6$ Women in These $11$ Gap, Which can be done by $\displaystyle \binom{11}{6}\times 6!.$

So Total no. of Arrangement in which no $2$ woman sit together is $\displaystyle 10! \times \binom{11}{6}\times 6!$

And Total Probability $\displaystyle = \frac{\bf{Favourable \; cases}}{\bf{Total \; Cases}} = \frac{10!\times \binom{11}{6}\times 6!}{16!}$